# How to set the program architecture for the compiler in VS Code?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

I wrote the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("size of void pointer in bytes : %d\n", sizeof(void*));
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Windows 10 now, hence, I installed the gcc compiler (MinGW for Windows). Now I want to compile my program once for the 32 bit architecture and then for 64 bit architecture. In order to do so, I added `m32` to the `args` parameter in `launch.json`, then compiled the program. After that, I done the same thing but for the 64 bit architecture (added `m64` flag).

In both cases the output of the program was:

```
size of void pointer in bytes : 8
```

That made me wonder. If I compile my program in Visual Studio (there you can choose the architecture pretty simple, in the dropdown menu next to the "green arrow"), then the word size is 4 bytes (32 bit architecture) and 8 bytes (64 bit architecture) as it should be.

I also tried to use `-march=i386` for the 32 bit architecture but it does not help me, the pointer was still 8 byte long. It seems that the passed arguments do not affect the architecture at all. Am I missing something or using the wrong arguments for my purpose?

My `launch.json` file (with `-m32` flag):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": ["-m32"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\Compilers\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launch.json` contains commands describing how to launch the compiled files. `args` are command-line arguments passed to the program (`argc`,`argv`), not the compiler.

You need to setup `tasks.json` which basically executes scripts.

Search for (ctrl+shift+P for me) `Tasks:Configure Task` or `Task:Configure Default build Task`. Or you can find them in the Terminal menu.

It can find `gcc` on its own and create a default task for it which compiles the currently active file. Unfortunately, I do not have experience with managing multi-file projects direclty in VSCode, so I cannot help more, but you should be able to find some default `tasks.json` for C++ on the internet. Or go with CMake or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution. However, now I get an another error. I understand that it, strictly speaking, an other question, but maybe you know why it happens (I passed -m32):
unrecognised emulation mode: 32.exe
Supported emulations: i386pep i386pe
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I also tried i386pep and i386pe - it does not help.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know, I am guessing that MinGW simply does not support this option?

Comment: Possible. I'll see what I can do with this error. Thank you for your answer.